# Is there a faster algorithm to compute prime numbers up to a given limit?

Tags: c++

To your knowledge, is there a faster algorithm to compute
prime numbers up to a given number ?

I managed to compute primes up to 1 Billion in about 18 seconds
on my fast Desktop.

I managed to compute primes up to 400 Billions in less than 2.5 hours,
but it require about 26 Gigs of free ram.

So, is there something faster ?

Try the code, it's fun to watch the debugging output with large numbers.

Xtian.

```
$ cat Prime2.cpp 
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Title: Computing primes numbers
//        this algorithm is near O(1) (linear)
//
//  Note: Using a bitmap rather than an array of "unsigned long long"
//        is a lot more memory efficient and really fast nevertheless.
//
// Author: Christian Robert
//   Date: 2021-11-01
//
// To compile: gcc -Wall -O3 -o Prime2 Prime2.cpp -lstdc++ -lm
//
// @todo: May be make it multithreads. That should be very difficult
//        and I'm not sure at all it would be faster...
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>


typedef unsigned long long ULL;
static const ULL LEFT_ONE = (ULL) 0x8000000000000000;

static unsigned long Debug = 1;  // 0, 1 or 2

// ---------------------
// Begin of class Bitmap

class Bitmap
{
  public:
    Bitmap (ULL size);
   ~Bitmap (void);

    bool GetBit (ULL pos);
    void SetBit (ULL pos);
    void ClrBit (ULL pos);

    int bm_bits_per_ULL;
    ULL bm_bits_size;
    ULL bm_real_size;
    ULL *bm_vector;
};

Bitmap::Bitmap (ULL size)
{
  bm_bits_per_ULL = sizeof(ULL)*8;
  bm_bits_size = size;
  bm_real_size = (bm_bits_size+127)/bm_bits_per_ULL;
  bm_real_size = bm_real_size >> 1;  // Only Odd numbers, optimizing for memory

  bm_vector = new ULL[bm_real_size];

  for (ULL i=0; i<bm_real_size ; ++i)
    bm_vector[i] = 0xffffffffffffffff; // Assume every ODD number is a prime number
}

Bitmap::~Bitmap (void)
{
  if (bm_vector) delete bm_vector;
  bm_vector = NULL;
}

bool Bitmap::GetBit (ULL at)
{
  ULL pos;
  unsigned off;

  if (at == 2) return 1;        // 2 is a prime number
  if ((at & 1) == 0) return 0;  // Even numbers are not prime numbers

  at = (at >> 1) + 1;

  pos = at/bm_bits_per_ULL;
  off = at%bm_bits_per_ULL;
  return ((ULL)0) != (bm_vector[pos] & (LEFT_ONE>>off));
}

void Bitmap::SetBit(ULL at)
{
  ULL pos;
  unsigned off;

  if (at == 2) return;
  if ((at & 1) == 0) return;

  at = (at >> 1) + 1;

  pos = at/bm_bits_per_ULL;
  off = at%bm_bits_per_ULL;
  if (Debug>1) fprintf (stderr, "SetBit pos=%'llu, off=%'u\n", pos, off);

  bm_vector[pos] = bm_vector[pos] | (LEFT_ONE >> off);
}

void Bitmap::ClrBit(ULL at)
{
  ULL pos;
  unsigned off;

  if (at == 2) return;
  if ((at & 1) == 0) return;

  at = (at >> 1) + 1;

  pos = at/bm_bits_per_ULL;
  off = at%bm_bits_per_ULL;
  if (Debug>1) fprintf (stderr, "ClrBit pos=%'llu, off=%u\n", pos, off);

  bm_vector[pos] = bm_vector[pos] & ~((LEFT_ONE) >> off);
}

// End of class Bitmap
// -------------------

// ---------------------------
// Get a microsecond timestamp
// ---------------------------
const char *TS(void)
{
  #define MAX_RECURSION 8 // Not usefull in this program but may be elsewhere if reused.

  static char curtime[MAX_RECURSION][64];
  static int  curidx = 0;
  struct tm *tm;
  struct timeval tv;
  int    to_return;

  gettimeofday (&tv, NULL);

  to_return = curidx;

  tm = localtime (&tv.tv_sec);

  snprintf (curtime[curidx++], sizeof(curtime[0]),
            "%04d-%02d-%02d@%02d:%02d:%02d.%06ld:",
            tm->tm_year+1900, tm->tm_mon+1, tm->tm_mday,
            tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec,
            tv.tv_usec);

  if (curidx >= MAX_RECURSION) curidx = 0;

  return curtime[to_return];
}

// ----------------------------------------------------
// Set a bit in the bitmap and clear all multiples bits
// ----------------------------------------------------

void SetPrime (Bitmap* bm, ULL number)
{
  if (Debug>0) fprintf (stderr, "%s New prime number %'llu, Clearing bits multiples of %'llu upto %'llu ... ",
                        TS(), number, number, bm->bm_bits_size);

  bm->SetBit (number);  // not usefull, bit is supposed to be already ON

  if (Debug > 1) fprintf(stderr, "\n");

  for (ULL i=2*number ; i <= bm->bm_bits_size ; i += number)
  {
    bm->ClrBit(i);
  }
  if (Debug>0) fprintf (stderr, "Done.\n");
}

// --------------------
// Clearing a prime bit
// --------------------

void ClrPrime (Bitmap* bm, ULL number)
{
  bm->ClrBit (number);
}

// --------------
// Usage(argv[0])
// --------------

void Usage (const char *progname)
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage: [\"time\"] %s [-d debug_level] { [-n upto_number] | upto_number } > outfile\n", progname);
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

// ------------
// main program
// ------------

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  setlocale (LC_NUMERIC, "en_US.utf8");

  extern char *optarg;

  int opt, flag_n = 0;
  ULL number = 0; // Default

  while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:d:")) != -1)
  {
    switch (opt)
    {
      case 'n':
        number = strtoull (optarg, NULL, 10);
        flag_n = 1;
        break;

      case 'd':
        Debug = strtoul (optarg, NULL, 10);
        break;

      default: /* '?' */
        Usage(argv[0]);
    }
  }

  if (flag_n == 0)
  {
    if (optind >= argc)
    { 
      fprintf (stderr, "Required missing \"-n upto_number\" OR \"upto_number\".\n\n");
      Usage (argv[0]);
    } else {
      number = strtoull (argv[optind], NULL, 10); // Get it from command first non-optionnal args
    }
  }

  if (number < 2)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "Your \"upto_number\" has no sence.\n");
    Usage (argv[0]);
  }

  // Allocate the Huge array (this may fail if not enough memory)

  Bitmap *bm = NULL;

  try {
    bm = new Bitmap(number);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    fprintf (stderr, "Not enough memory to compute primes upto %'llu.\n", number);
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

//
// Target number =  47,055,833,459 for 2 Billions primes (16m9s on my computer, 3+Gigs of ram)
//                 400,000,000,100 for ? Billions primes (135m  on my computer, 26+Gigs of ram)
//

  fprintf (stderr, "%s bm_bits_per_ULL = %u\n", TS(), bm->bm_bits_per_ULL);
  fprintf (stderr, "%s bm_bits_size = %'llu\n", TS(), bm->bm_bits_size);
  fprintf (stderr, "%s bm_real_size = %'llu (%'llu Memory Bytes)\n", TS(), bm->bm_real_size, bm->bm_real_size*8);

// Bootstrap the Bitmap

  ClrPrime (bm, 0);    // 0 is not a prime number
  ClrPrime (bm, 1);    // 1 is not a prime number
  SetPrime (bm, 2);    // 2 is a prime number

// Compute prime numbers {3 .. number}

  ULL SQRT = sqrt(bm->bm_bits_size);

  for (ULL i=3; i<=SQRT ; i+=2)
  {
    bool was = bm->GetBit(i);
    if (was) SetPrime(bm, i);
  }

// All computation done, now print the results

  fprintf (stderr, "%s Writing result to stdout...\n", TS());

  for (ULL i=2 ; i<=bm->bm_bits_size ; ++i)
  {
    if (bm->GetBit(i) == 1) printf ("%llu\n", i);
  }

  fprintf (stderr, "%s All done.\n", TS());

  delete bm;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do your research ;) More then enough literature around, eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin. It is also not strange to expect a memory speed tradeoff. Also a bitmap why? have a look here : https://www.cppstories.com/2017/04/packing-bools/

Comment: The "bitmap why" was about to get the maximum possible primes on my own computer in a finite time. I will look closely at both your links. Thanks.

Comment: If you want the maximum number of primes you will probably have to trade in some speed to be able to pack as much information in your bits as you can.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 100% mathematical test that will check if a number `P` is prime or composite, called [AKS Primality Test.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test)

The concept is simple: given a number `P`, if all the coefficients of `(x-1)^P - (x^P-1)` are divisible by `P,` then `P` is a prime number, otherwise it is a composite number.

For instance, given P = 3, would give the polynomial:

```
   (x-1)^3 - (x^3 - 1)
 = x^3 + 3x^2 - 3x - 1 - (x^3 - 1)
 = 3x^2 - 3x
```

And the coefficients are both divisible by `3`, therefore the number is prime.

And example where `P = 4`, which is NOT a prime would yield:

```
   (x-1)^4 - (x^4-1)
 = x^4 - 4x^3 + 6x^2 - 4x + 1 - (x^4 - 1)
 = -4x^3 + 6x^2 - 4x
```

And here we can see that the coefficients 6 is not divisible by 4, therefore it is NOT prime.

The polynomial `(x-1)^P` will `P+1` terms and can be found using combination. So, this test will run in `O(n)` runtime, so I don't know how useful this would be since you can simply iterate over `i` from `0` to p and test for the remainder.

Comment: Thank you for the algorithm, I will try to implement it. As I see this algorithm will not be a memory hug at all.

Comment: is that working

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes, this the fastest algorithm to compute the maximum number
of Primes in the minimum of time, given your computer memory.

no other algotithm can compete with this one.

the problem is that you need 1/2 bit of free memory for each
tested numbers, so, 100 Billions need 6.3 Gigs of memory...

A trillion will need over 64 Gigs of memory... and so on

Xtian.

[xtian@fedora:/home/xtian] $ ./Prime2 1000000000 -d0 | wc -l
2021-12-16@00:03:57.516219: bm_bits_per_ULL = 64
2021-12-16@00:03:57.516291: bm_bits_size = 1,000,000,000
2021-12-16@00:03:57.516297: bm_real_size = 7,812,500 (62,500,000 Memory Bytes)
2021-12-16@00:04:08.117452: Writing result to stdout...
2021-12-16@00:04:14.508408: All done.
50847534

[xtian@fedora:/home/xtian] $ ./Prime2 10000000000 -d0 | wc -l
2021-12-16@00:04:35.905754: bm_bits_per_ULL = 64
2021-12-16@00:04:35.905819: bm_bits_size = 10,000,000,000
2021-12-16@00:04:35.905824: bm_real_size = 78,125,000 (625,000,000 Memory Bytes)
2021-12-16@00:06:35.734539: Writing result to stdout...
2021-12-16@00:07:38.015008: All done.
455052511

[xtian@fedora:/home/xtian] $ ./Prime2 100000000000 -d0 | wc -l
2021-12-16@00:08:15.321612: bm_bits_per_ULL = 64
2021-12-16@00:08:15.322381: bm_bits_size = 100,000,000,000
2021-12-16@00:08:15.334243: bm_real_size = 781,250,000 (6,250,000,000 Memory Bytes)
2021-12-16@00:30:33.727373: Writing result to stdout...
2021-12-16@00:40:30.536159: All done.
4118054813
```